# elfinder 2.1 file manager allowed extensions

Tags: jquery, elfinder

I need to limit allowed extensions that file uploader dialog contain. Currently (by default) it has "*.*" mask. I need only mp3,wav,jpg,png files.

There is options that files is showed in directoryes:

onlyMimes: ['image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'audio/mpeg'],
 fileFilter : /.*.(png|jpg)$/i,

But it does not meet what i need.

Comment: Have a look at the url: https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Client-configuration-options#handlers where they have given an example of an "upload" event. It will help you to get closer towards your solution. :)

Comment: inspecting elfinder full code  i find input creation and impossibility to change it through options. added 'accept' attrib manually and now it woorks.but this is not a solution, patching it.

Comment: It might be the patching from your end, but if you requested the same thing from plugin developers they too could have went down the same way and then while using that, it couldn't have felt as patch to us. So you got solution is better than nothing. :)

Answer (score 0):

path /php/connector.minimal.php

remove  line: 157 and 169